# How to bind a Kotlin Function in Guice

Tags: kotlin, guice

I have a Kotlin class similar to this:

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(val work: (Int) -> Unit)) { ... }
```

Neither the `bind` nor the `@Provides` is working:

```
class FunctionModule : AbstractModule() {

    override fun configure() {
        bind(object : TypeLiteral<Function1<Int, Unit>>() {}).toInstance({})
    }

    @Provides
    fun workFunction(): (Int) -> Unit = { Unit }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> No implementation for kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1< ? super java.lang.Integer, kotlin.Unit> was bound.

How can I inject an implementation for a Kotlin function using Guice?

Comment: Note that `{ Unit }` can be simplified with `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr - Use:

```
bind(object : TypeLiteral<Function1<Int, @JvmSuppressWildcards Unit>>() {})
    .toInstance({})
```

---

In the class

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(val work: (Int) -> Unit)) { ... }
```

the parameter `work` has a type (as least according to Guice) of:

```
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Integer, kotlin.Unit>
```

However,

```
bind(object : TypeLiteral<Function1<Int, Unit>>() {}).toInstance({})
```

registers a type of `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<? super java.lang.Integer, **? extends** kotlin.Unit>`

Changing `bind` to `bind(object : TypeLiteral<Function1<Int, **@JvmSuppressWildcards** Unit>>() {}).toInstance({})`
to remove the variance on the return type allows Guice to properly inject the function.

Answer (score 0):

What if you'll inject `Function1<Int,Unit>` instead of `(Int) -> Unit`?

Comment: That's what `bind(object : TypeLiteral<Function1<Int, Unit>>() {}).toInstance({})` (from my question) does. The error that it generates is shown in the question.